# Right border shifts to bottom line

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/W9LXd/

I want the div under the #araclar to have it's right border stay in the same line. How can I prevent it from shifting?

CSS:

```
 #düzenleyici{
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
    }
    #araclar{
        width:auto;
        height:50px;
        background:#EEEEEE;
        display:block;
        padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }
    #araclar>div{
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="düzenleyici">
    <div id="araclar">
        <div>
            Renk
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change display: inline to display: inline-block

Comment: You are always welcome buddy.  /* Code is poerty */

Answer (score 1):

Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

Use: http://jsfiddle.net/W9LXd/1/

`display: inline-block` instead of display-inline

Or give a specific width.

Answer (score 1):

IMO there is no problem with your CSS

Your HTML is malformed, Please close the inner most `div` - on which you have set `display:inline`

```
<div id="düzenleyici">
    <div id="araclar">
        <div>
            Renk
        </div> <!-- yOU have not closed the tag here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/bU4zn/)